# Unable to deploy microservice on cumulocity

Tags: docker, microservices, cumulocity

I created a microservice using steps given on this link https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/java/java-microservice
i was able to start the microservice using docker image and able to subscribe to it using this api :POST {URL}/tenant/tenants/{TENANT_ID}/applications
 but i am getting these errors :Error while reacting on microservice subscription

Also the api for deploying the microservice is not working and giving a 500 internal server error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvbkO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the microservices enabled as part of your tenant, else you will get this error.